# Angular Validator to allow null or apply length

Tags: angular

I have searched online but could not find a solution for this yet.

I have a update form for users and would like to apply a custom validator on the password control.

Password value should either be blank or its `minLength` should be greater than 4.

To double check that other fields are not causing trouble I have assigned default values to other fields

Form is initialised as shown below:

```
this.updateUserForm = this.fb.group({
    first_name: ['John', [Validators.required]],
    last_name: ['Doe', [Validators.required]],
    email: ['test@email.com', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [UpdatePasswordValidator.validPasswordOrEmpty]],
});
```

Custom validator:

```
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

export class UpdatePasswordValidator {
    static validPasswordOrEmpty(fc: FormControl) {
        if (!fc.value || fc.value.length >= 4) {
            return null;
        }
        return ({validPasswordOrEmpty: true});
    }
}
```

Here is my `html` code, got rid of all other fields to debug.

```
<ion-list lines="full">
    <form [formGroup]="updateUserForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()">

        <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="fixed">Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <ion-button [disabled]="!updateUserForm.valid" color="primary" shape="full" type="submit"
                            expand="block">Update User
                </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </form>
</ion-list>
```

Following is `edit.page.ts`

```
export class EditPage implements OnInit {

    updateUserForm: FormGroup;
    id: any;
    errors = null;

    constructor(
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
        public fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params.id;
        this.updateUserForm = this.fb.group({
            password: ['', UpdatePasswordValidator.validPasswordOrEmpty],
        });
    }
}
```

Created the above custom validator but it does not allow empty value. when `password` value is blank `updateUserForm.valid` is always false.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Debug the validator to see if it ever returns `({validPasswordOrEmpty: true})`. If it doesn't, the error is most likely from another control.

Comment: Yes it does when the length is between 1 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

`form` can be invalid because other fields can be invalid. To verify if that particular control is valid or not, use `this.updateUserForm.controls.passowrd.isValid;` Your custom validator function looks correct.